# Order bars by difference between variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

My intention is to plot a barchart, with to variables visible: 
`"HH_FIN_EX", "ACT_IND_CON_EXP"` but having them ordered by the variable `diff`, in ascending order. `diff` itself should not be included in chart

```
library(eurostat)
library(tidyverse)

#getting the data
data1 <- get_eurostat("nama_10_gdp",time_format = "num")

#filtering
data_1_4 <- data1 %>% 
        filter(time=="2016", 
               na_item %in% c("B1GQ", "P31_S14_S15", "P41"), 
               geo %in% c("BE","BG","CZ","DK","DE","EE","IE","EL","ES","FR","HR","IT","CY","LV","LT","LU","HU","MT","NL","AT","PL","PT","RO","SI","SK","FI","SE","UK"), 
               unit=="CP_MEUR")%>% select(-unit, -time)

#transformations and calculations
data_1_4 <- data_1_4 %>% 
        spread(na_item, values)%>% 
        na.omit() %>% 
        mutate(HH_FIN_EX = P31_S14_S15/B1GQ, ACT_IND_CON_EXP=P41/B1GQ, diff=ACT_IND_CON_EXP-HH_FIN_EX) %>%
        gather(na_item, values,  2:7)%>%
        filter(na_item %in% c("HH_FIN_EX", "ACT_IND_CON_EXP", "diff")) 
#plotting
ggplot(data=data_1_4, aes(x=reorder(geo, values), y=values, fill=na_item))+
        geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge(), colour="black")+
        labs(title="", x="Countries", y="As percentage of GDP")
```

[image]

I appreciate any suggestions how to do this, as `aes(x=reorder(geo, values[values=="diff"])` results in an error.

Comment: Justai, what's `data1`? Also, `diff` is  function in `base` so better not to name you variables like that.

Comment: Added the missing code line.  Thanks for the advice not to use the `diff`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't include `diff` (your result column) when using `gather`, it complicates things.
Change line `gather(na_item, values,  2:7)` to `gather(na_item, values, 2:6)`.

You can use this code to calculate difference and order (using `dplyr::arange`) rows in descending order:

```
plotData <- data_1_4 %>% 
        spread(na_item, values) %>% 
        na.omit() %>% 
        mutate(HH_FIN_EX = P31_S14_S15 / B1GQ, 
               ACT_IND_CON_EXP = P41 / B1GQ, 
               diff = ACT_IND_CON_EXP - HH_FIN_EX) %>%
        gather(na_item, values, 2:6) %>%
        filter(na_item %in% c("HH_FIN_EX", "ACT_IND_CON_EXP")) %>%
        arrange(desc(diff))
```

And plot it with:

```
ggplot(plotData, aes(geo, values, fill = na_item))+
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", color = "black") +
    labs(x = "Countries", 
         y = "As percentage of GDP") +
    scale_x_discrete(limits = plotData$geo)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly figure out the order that you want -- this is stored in `country_order` below -- and force the factor `geo` to have its levels in that order.  Then run `ggplot` after filtering out the `diff` variable.  So replace your call to `ggplot` with the following:

```
country_order = (data_1_4 %>% filter(na_item == 'diff') %>% arrange(values))$geo
data_1_4$geo = factor(data_1_4$geo, country_order)
ggplot(data=filter(data_1_4, na_item != 'diff'), aes(x=geo, y=values, fill=na_item))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge(), colour="black")+
  labs(title="", x="Countries", y="As percentage of GDP")
```

Doing this, I get the plot below:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

is this what you are looking for?

```
data_1_4 %>% mutate(Val = fct_reorder(geo, values, .desc = TRUE)) %>%
      filter(na_item %in% c("HH_FIN_EX", "ACT_IND_CON_EXP")) %>%
       ggplot(aes(x=Val, y=values, fill=na_item)) +
        geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge(), colour="black") +
        labs(title="", x="Countries", y="As percentage of GDP")
```

[image: dd]